# howto run cookbooks from server on local machine

Tags: chef-infra

I have chef-server with cookbooks (recepies) and added hosts.

How to I can run  cookbook on local server?
I know that chef made it automatically, by default per each 30 minutes,
but I want run it ammidiately.

PS: I know about chef-solo, but I need run cookbooks from server without any by-hand manipulations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run Chef on demand by doing `sudo chef-client`, but it's a bit safer to send the chef-client daemon a USR1 signal:

```
$ sudo killall -USR1 chef-client
```

This tells the chef-client daemon to start another run immediately.  It's safer to do this as there is no chance of having two chef-clients running at the same time.

(The chef-client run is actually delayed from up to the number of seconds specified by the `--splay` option to the chef-client daemon so it doesn't happen exactly-right-now-at-this-very-minute).